# Transfer settings to new version of Blender

Tags: interface, customization, versions

I use Mac OSX 10.9.5. A year ago, I downloaded 2.75a, and today, I downloaded version 2.77a. I downloaded both via .zip file from blender.org and dragged each into the Applications folder of my Mac.

In 2.75a, I had done some painstaking remapping to accommodate my Magic Mouse and Apple Wireless Keyboard, in addition to a pretty shiny custom theme. I didn't want to redo these settings.

How could I transfer my old settings into the new version? Apparently due to my method of download, "Copy Previous Settings" did not show on the splash screen. I searched "Copy Previous Settings" in the new version via the spacebar, and it returned an error: "Users/aubrie/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.76 does not exist". From this, I figured how to copy my old preferences.

Answer (score 3):

1. Find `Users/yourname/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.75/config/userpref.blend`
2. Right click and select *Copy* `userpref.blend`
3. Navigate to `Users/yourname/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.77/config/`
4. Right click and select *Paste* item.

Comment: Aubrie, are you sure about that destination? Unless I'm reading it wrong, you're copying the "userpref.blend" file right back into the same location you copied it from. Also, since I think your answer applies to Windows machines, too, it might be more general just to do a search of the drive containing the operating system for the file "userpref.blend", rather than trying to navigate to the specific location. On some windows machines, the "userpref.blend" file is in a hidden folder, which cannot be navigated to by "ordinary" means.

Comment: @brasshat You're totally right. I committed a typo. Step 3 should have said 2.77, not 2.75. Fixed it now.

Good idea about conducting a normal search. That might get messy if someone has multiple previous versions of Blender installed.

Comment: Aubrie, I **do** have multiple previous versions of Blender installed, and when I just tested it for the answer, It did find the previous userpref.blend files for each one. But expanding the search results just a bit, it showed the folder containing each of the separate userpref.blend files, so it was easy to figure out which went with 2.75, and which went with 2.71.

Comment: @brasshat That's good to know!
I should clarify that in my original questing, I didn't know to search for "userpref.blend". Navigating to specific folders was how I learned that "userpref.blend" is the thing I needed.

Comment: I dragged both Scripts and Addons from the 2.78 to the 2.79 folder and it worked great.

Comment: Works between windows and linux aswell

Answer (score 3):

You can always use the new [Blender Cloud Sync](https://cloud.blender.org/blog/introducing-blender-sync) addon. It requires a Blender ID (free) and the addon (free). It allows you to upload your preferences to the cloud, and download them anywhere in Blender.

[image: Addon Gif]
(Image from cloud.blender.org)

Comment: In case this helps others: When I switched from 2.79b to 2.80, my old method didn't work, so I used this cloud sync add-on and it worked great. I had to download the add-on (directly from the .zip file, no need to unzip) to both 2.79b and 2.80, sign in within Blender (using this other add-on: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141746/where-is-the-blender-id-add-on-preference-pane/146230), upload settings in 2.79b, then download the settings to 2.80.