# Importing and exporting blender user preference files?

Tags: customization

I spent some time doing a project in two different computers (personal computer and a shared one in the 3d course), and one of the annoying things was that I always had to reconfigure Blender. It seems that not all settings are bound to the `.blend` file (things like solid OpenGL lights for the viewport).

Either Blender stores the settings in its installation directory or in the user folder, and both aren't that practical to access in a computer that's not yours (some lock the access to the `Program Files` folder, for example).

So, is there any plugin that can import and export the user preferences to/from a convenient file (a `.xml`, maybe?) Installing plugins is something I've been able to do even when I'm not logged in as admin the course machine, so it's a good workaround.

Comment: All settings are saved in either `startup.blend` or `userpref.blend` both of which are saved in the app data folder, Exceptions may be keymaps which can be exported anyways, and per-file preferences which may override defaults. If you jump computers often consider a [portable install](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78121/can-i-change-default-folder-to-save-startup-file-startup-blend-and-userpref-ble/78128#78128) from a zipped setup instead. No need for aany addons.

Comment: You can simply copy the startup.blend file and windows userprefs.blend to other computers for a smoother experience. One thing to be aware of is that the addons you are using have to be available as well. An alternative is to use the blendercloud sync addon, you do need an account on the site but it does not need to be a paid one. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57073/transfer-settings-to-new-version-of-blender/57079#57079

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the free Blender Cloud add-on to sync your preferences between different computers. It's a free feature, just requires a Cloud account. More info at https://cloud.blender.org/services