# Where is the Blender ID add-on preference pane?

Tags: customization, blender-id

For some reason I seem to have lost all my **[Blender Sync](https://cloud.blender.org/blog/introducing-blender-sync)** preferences. I reinstalled the add-on which was missing, but the preferences pane is asking me to log in:

[image]

I cannot find out how to log in, I restarted after installing, and looked in all the preference panes but didn't find it.

***How does one log in with their Blender ID to use Blender Sync?***

Comment: Have you contacted blendercloud directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to activate another addon called Blender ID authentication. You put your credentials in the Blender ID addon and automatically the Blender Cloud addon will login
[image]